# How to add a JInternalFrame to JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jinternalframe

I have my `JFrame`, and I want to attach to a button an ActionListener that triggers the `JInternalFrame`.

I do:

```
private void aboutMenuItemActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    AboutFrame about = new AboutFrame(); //jInternalFrame
    this.add(about);        
}
```

But it doesn't bring it to front. What did I miss?

[image]

Comment: What do you mean "bind to a button" ? Do you just mean you want the internal frame to appear when the button is pressed?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Sry for my bad english. I mean that the button has attached an AcionListener that shows the jInternalFrame.

Comment: Finally I used a JFrame, best solution.

Answer (score 2):

You probable want to use a `JDesktopPane`, then set the content pane of your frame to the desktop pane

```
    JDesktopPane desktop = new JDesktopPane(); //a specialized layered pane
    createFrame(); //create first "window"
    setContentPane(desktop);
```

Then you can do something like this

```
private void aboutMenuItemActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)
{                                              
    AboutFrame about = new AboutFrame();           <--- JInternalFrame
    about.setVisible(true); //necessary as of 1.3  <--- set it visible
    desktop.add(about);                            <--- add to desktop
    try {
        about.setSelected(true);                   <--- set it selected
    } catch (java.beans.PropertyVetoException e) {}        

}
```

---

See [How to Us Internal Frames](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/internalframe.html)

---

**UDATE**

Run this example, I made on NetBeans GUI Builder also. It works fine, without the behavior yout're talking about.

```
public class NewJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    public NewJFrame() {
        initComponents();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jDesktopPane1 = new javax.swing.JDesktopPane();
        jMenuBar1 = new javax.swing.JMenuBar();
        jMenu1 = new javax.swing.JMenu();
        jMenu2 = new javax.swing.JMenu();
        jMenuItem1 = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jDesktopPane1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jDesktopPane1);
        jDesktopPane1.setLayout(jDesktopPane1Layout);
        jDesktopPane1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jDesktopPane1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 376, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        jDesktopPane1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jDesktopPane1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 302, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        jMenu1.setText("File");
        jMenuBar1.add(jMenu1);

        jMenu2.setText("About");

        jMenuItem1.setText("About");
        jMenuItem1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jMenuItem1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        jMenu2.add(jMenuItem1);

        jMenuBar1.add(jMenu2);

        setJMenuBar(jMenuBar1);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jDesktopPane1)
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jDesktopPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap())
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jMenuItem1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
        AboutFrame about = new AboutFrame();
        about.setVisible(true);
        jDesktopPane1.add(about);
        try {
            about.setSelected(true);
        } catch (java.beans.PropertyVetoException e) {
        }
    }                                          


    public static void main(String args[]) {

        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new NewJFrame().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JDesktopPane jDesktopPane1;
    private javax.swing.JMenu jMenu1;
    private javax.swing.JMenu jMenu2;
    private javax.swing.JMenuBar jMenuBar1;
    private javax.swing.JMenuItem jMenuItem1;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

AboutFrame.java

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JInternalFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class AboutFrame extends JInternalFrame{

    public AboutFrame() {
        add(new Panel());
        pack();
    }

    private class Panel extends JPanel {
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);

            g.drawString("About Screen", 100, 100);
        }
        public Dimension getPreferredSize(){
            return new Dimension(300, 300);
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

---

Steps I took

1. Opened a new JFrame form
2. Dragged a `JDesktopPane` to the main frame and expanded it the size of the frame
3. Dragged a `JMenuBar` to the top of the frame
4. Dragged a `JMenuItem` to the `JMenuBar`
5. Added an event listener to the `JMenuItem`
6. Added the action code that i provided for you  earlier. That's all I did, and it works fine.

---

**EDIT**

A different apprach would be instead of using an `JInternalFrame` for this. Use a modal `JDialog`. You can create it the same way you did the `JInternalFrame` , and show it the same way. This will guarantee you don't get this result. :)

Comment: It works. But when the frame is shown, the main frame is covered with a black layer. I tryed: desktop.setOpaque(false); but doesn't work.

Comment: Also can you post your code, if it's not too much. Or post an small runnable example the duplicate the problem

Comment: Run my example, I created on Netbeans GUI Builder, It works fine. No black Layer

Comment: I may have misled you in the original answer. I Had a typo. This `desktop.add(frame);` Shoul've have been this `desktop.add(about);`

Comment: Yeah, it's the same in my case. But I want that the desktopPane to be transparent, not to be filled in that grey/blue color. Is possible? Thank you.

Comment: If you delete the `DesktopPane` and just use this `NewJFrame.this.add(about);` it works.

Comment: Then this is what happen: http://img202.imageshack.us/img202/5261/nwty.png As I said in my first post. I suspect that my GUI hasn't been created well.

Comment: Did you create the Internal Frame as a different form file?

Comment: Yes. I have AboutFrame.java.

Comment: Try to `revalidate()` and `repaint()` in the action method after add the internal frame

Comment: Honestly I'm not sure then. I _always_ use Internal Frames with `JDestopPane`. But I hand code. I'm not sure how to get rid of the back ground though, as it's issued with the Look & Feel

Comment: Thnaks for your help & patience. Hope I find some solution ;)

Comment: I just thought of another Solution. instead of using an Internal frame for this. Use a modal JDialog. You can create it the same way you did the `JInternal` frame, and show it the same way. This will guarantee you dont get this result. :)